# Using uniq in ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby, activerecord

Running this line of code

```
Activity.uniq.select(:ip).where("created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY").count
```

Returns the number of all lines (without the uniquness filter) although the SQL is correct (with the DISTINCT keyword)

If I run this command in 2 steps:

```
c = Activity.uniq.select(:ip).where("created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY")
c.size
```

Then I get the right count.

How can it be?

Thank you

Comment: What is the SQL that's being generated for the first one?

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(`activities`.`ip`) FROM `activities` WHERE (created_at > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally `DISTINCT` will remove duplicate results from a result set but it won't do any grouping. Since you have one row in a `COUNT` result, you won't see any effect. What you really want is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT activities.ip) FROM activities WHERE ...
```

Note that you want a count *of* the distinct activities, not a distinct count.

I'm not sure how you'd manage to emit this SQL using ActiveRecord. You may need to resort to using the ActiveRecord `connection` directly and use `select_value` for such an unusual sort of inquiry unless you can coach `select` to do it for you.

Comment: Oppss... Didn't noticed the query.. Thank you!